# real time messaging for multi player game on ios

Tags: ios, real-time, messaging, multiplayer

Building a multi player iOS game where players compete one against the other. Nature of the game is synchronous. Basically, players either invite each other through facebook, email, etc and then start playing.

We debate what is the best strategy for facilitating the real time communication between players (sending events, etc). Coming from web development, we used comet and long polling which worked great. However, it's not clear what's the best way to achieve that on iOS.

Seems like APN (Apple Push Notifications) is not suitable in our case for two reasons: the delay can be pretty significant, up to few seconds, as far as we understand. Also, using APN requires the user to authorize notifications. If the user doesn't authorize this then it won't be possible to play the game.

Also, we understand Apple's Game Kit (Game Center) can be of value in our case however it's not clear how it interacts with invites through facebook etc. Also, not clear if we need to get into bed with Apple's Game Center and how it'll affect the user experience.

Any guidance on this matter as well as other options that you might think of would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Before you read the rest, a disclaimer: I work for Realtime.co but I do believe I can help here so I'm not trying to "pitch a sale".

If you need to have real time updates, you can check out Realtime ([www.realtime.co](http://www.realtime.co)). It's basically a set of tools for developers to use real time technologies on their projects. It uses websockets but does fallback to whatever the user's browser supports (such as long polling, for example) if you are using a browser (which is not your case, but it's always good to know).

Behind Realtime you have a one-to-one/one-to-many/many-to-many messaging system that will transport your messages to and from your users.

There's a iOS API too which you can use in your project. You can download it here: http://www.xrtml.org/downloads_62.html#ios and check the documentation here: http://docs.xrtml.org/getting_started/hello_message.html#ios.

There's also a plus which is the fact that the Realtime framework is actually cross-platform. This means that you can even have your iOS players to communicate with players using Android, Windows Phone, HTML5, Flash, etc. if you decide on expanding your game to other platforms.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

I'll just provide some insights on the question.

APN should never be used for synchro communication as for iOS at least, you'll never have both way communication (basically the Apple APN servers are pushing an information to the device).

You should probably play with C sockets in order to open a tunnel (depends if your game is real time or not).

Using the Apple Framework GameKit is great! But might take some time to understand all the functionnalities.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Gree
https://developer.gree.net/en/

Parse:
https://www.parse.com/

Sparrow:
http://gamua.com/sparrow/

There are a few things that your talking about, there is the joining/starting of a game, and then the communication between the players.  They are not necessarily related.

You can use game-center and at the same time another framework for facebook, they are not mutually exclusive (but it would be more work.)